# C error: storage size isn't known

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a struct to be used in a Linked List that looks like this:

```
#ifndef MYGREP_H
#define MYGREP_H

typedef struct occurrenceType Occurrence;

struct occurrenceType {
    char* line;
    int lineNumber;
    int wordNumber;
    Occurrence *next;
};

#endif
```

but when I try to allocate memory using sizeof(Occurrence) I get the error "Invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Occurrence.'  I've tried several different structure declaration formats with no luck. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an exact error message?  Before I fixed the double r I got the same error message as you did, with clang 3.3.  After I fixed the typo it compiled cleanly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first struct typedef declaration:

```
                   v
typedef struct occurenceType Occurrence;
                   ^
```

has one 'r' on "occurencyType" but your definition:

```
           vv
struct occurrenceType {
           ^^ 
    char* line;
    int lineNumber;
    int wordNumber;
    Occurrence *next;
};
```

has two 'r's.

Answer (score 0):

Struct is user defined data type in c. Before the declaration of occurrenceType you are trying to use it and hence before its declaration or definition if you try to use it then it is an error. Your code should be

```
  #ifndef MYGREP_H
  #define MYGREP_H
  struct occurrenceType {
  char* line;
  int lineNumber;
  int wordNumber;
  Occurrence *next;
  };
  typedef struct occurrenceType Occurrence;
  #endif
```

First declaration then use it. Another it may be some spell mismatch so try to use this